# color code in SharePoint calendar

Tags: javascript

I have SharePoint calendar and I want the entries to be in color based on status.
If user add one entry and status is initially `pending` then that task would be in `green`, later it get changed to `in progress` then task color should change to `yellow` and `blue` for `resolved`.

```
Resolved=blue
in progress=yellow
pending=green
```

How can I achieve this, can anyone provide me javascript code for same

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using JavaScript to color code which you can find code for doing [here](http://arunsharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/sharepoint-2010-colour-code-calendar/) I'd recommend that you use the standard Overlay capabilities of SharePoint calendars.

1. Create three additional views Pending, Progress and Resolved which only show items in the appropriate status.
2. Change the default view to only show Status = "None".
3. In the "Calendar Tools|Calendar" ribbon tab click "Calendars Overlay"
4. For each of the three stati

   1. Click New Calendar
   2. Fill in information like this

      1. Calendar Name: Pending
      2. Type: SharePoint
      3. Color: Light Green
      4. Web URL: Leave alone
      5. Click Resolve
      6. Select right Calendar as List
      7. Select right View as List View
      8. Always Show: Checked

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This you can do by Out of the the Box SharePoint. You will not need JavaScript just try to follow below link, which will help you step by step

http://thinketg.com/sharepoint-color-coding-your-calendar-by-category-tutorial/

http://summit7systems.com/color-code-calendar-events-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

The below article was helpful in achieving this functionality using JavaScript:

http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/color-coded-calendar-sharepoint-online-using-javascript/